# Android : negative margins behave differently on different versions

Tags: android-fragments, android-view, android-relativelayout, layoutparams, margin

I am writing an application where I need to move a view from top to bottom but only when user moves it downward. To move this view I have a button below the view to drag. So initially I place the view beyond top of the view i.e. with negative margin equals the height and only the drag button is visible at the top to user. I see that this works perfectly on Lollipop and view is just at the position where bottom of view matches the top of screen. When I try it on Kitkat and lower versions, the view goes more towards top than the edge of screen. I have this everything in a RelativeLayout.

To show that view is dragged downward I am manipulating bottomMargin and topMargin properties on view.

Has anyone came across similar problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `negative margins behave differently` No, they behave **the same**. It's only that different OS versions can have different margins. See what's inside your `styles.xml` files.

Comment: Thank you. Can you be more specific of which property to look for in `styles.xml` ? I am actually setting these margins dynamically.

Comment: Not sure if it's in styles.xml or themes.xml. Look for anithing containing the word margin.

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue with use of FrameLayout. Thank you for help though.